# Recent versions of Firefox have no svgElm.offsetHeight property

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, svg

I just learned the most recent version(s) of firefox have deprecated `SVGSVGElement` API's. Sadly `.viewport` seem to be `undefined`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5duvgr6z/7

Have I missed a memo, or is this a firefox bug. If so, does anyone know any workarounds?

Comment: why don't you use `getBoundingClientRect()` ?

Comment: .viewport does not seem to work :/ (updated the fiddle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No version of Firefox has **ever** supported offsetHeight on SVG elements as it would be a bug to do so.

[offsetHeight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface) is a property of html elements only according to the CSSOM specification. It is unfortunate that other UAs do not follow the specification correctly as it confuses people into thinking it should be supported.

getBoundingClientRect and/or getBBox will allow you to calculate such things in a cross-browser way.

viewport is [underspecified](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=503855) and we're not sure how to implement it. I did try at one time. You could chase w3c to specify it in sufficient detail that it can be implemented.